# custom ppt templated changes doesn't render rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, render, presentation

I am attempting to render a powerpoint presentation from rmarkdown.
I downloaded this powerpoint template and associated files from [sol-eng](https://github.com/sol-eng/powerpoint/blob/master/examples/templates/rstudio-template.pptx) and am able to generate the powerpoint as is.

However, if I open the template and do 
`view -> slide master`
and adjust any of the slide master (i.e. change the background color)
`close slide master -> save`

I get the error "The file may be damaged or it may have been created in a pre-release version of PowerPoint." when I attempt to render the powerpoint.

I am unclear why using the template as is vs changing the background would generate an error in making the powerpoint presentation.

Any suggestions would be helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

it might be that R writes binary differently than Powerpoint. Is it possible to create a ioslide or beamer slide file with the original powerpoint file instead? If you do IOSlides or beamer, the view with only need a web browser and could be a more flexible file for presentation

Answer (score 0):

I used a different computer/version of powerpoint; adjusted the master slide and now it works - still unsure why I couldn't adjust with my version of powerpoint so I am guessing some versioning issue.